# How to retrieve the post from the circle in google plus

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

i am trying to retrieve the post from the Google Plus circles
I already succeed in retrieving the posts in profile of user and the user Profile details
Can You please help me out

Thanks in advance

My code is

```
 package main.java;

    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessProtectedResource;
    import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException;
    import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpRequest;
    import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpRequestInitializer;
    import com.google.api.services.plus.Plus;
    import com.google.api.services.plus.PlusRequest;
    import com.google.api.services.plus.model.*;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    public class Sample {
      private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Sample.class.getName());

      private static Plus plus;
      private static Plus unauthenticatedPlus;

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {
          setupTransport();

          getProfile();
          listActivities();
          getActivity();
        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
          log.severe(e.getResponse().parseAsString());
          throw e;
        }
      }

      /**
       * Setup the transport for our API calls.
       * @throws java.io.IOException when the transport cannot be created
       */
      private static void setupTransport() throws IOException {
        // Here's an example of an unauthenticated Plus object. In cases where you
        // do not need to use the /me/ path segment to discover the current user's
        // ID, you can skip the OAuth flow with this code.
        unauthenticatedPlus = Plus.builder(Util.TRANSPORT, Util.JSON_FACTORY)
            // When we do not specify access tokens, we must specify our API key instead
            // We do this using a JsonHttpRequestInitializer
            .setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new JsonHttpRequestInitializer() {
              @Override
              public void initialize(JsonHttpRequest jsonHttpRequest) throws IOException {
                PlusRequest plusRequest = (PlusRequest) jsonHttpRequest;
                plusRequest.setKey(Auth.GOOGLE_API_KEY);
              }
            }).build();

        // If, however, you need to use OAuth to identify the current user you must
        // create the Plus object differently. Most programs will need only one
        // of these since you can use an authenticated Plus object for any call.
        Auth.authorize();
        GoogleAccessProtectedResource requestInitializer =
            new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(
                Auth.getAccessToken(),
                Util.TRANSPORT,
                Util.JSON_FACTORY,
                Auth.CLIENT_ID,
                Auth.CLIENT_SECRET,
                Auth.getRefreshToken());
        plus = Plus.builder(Util.TRANSPORT, Util.JSON_FACTORY)
            .setHttpRequestInitializer(requestInitializer).build();
      }

      /**
       * List the public activities for the authenticated user
       *
       * @throws IOException if unable to call API
       */
      private static void listActivities() throws IOException {
        header("Search Activities for teja mariduvb");

        // Fetch the first page of activities
        Plus.Activities.Search listActivities = plus.activities().search();

        listActivities.setQuery("teja mariduvb");
        listActivities.setMaxResults(20L);

        ActivityFeed feed;
        try {
          feed = listActivities.execute();
        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
          log.severe(Util.extractError(e));
          throw e;
        }
        // Keep track of the page number in case we're listing activities
        // for a user with thousands of activities. We'll limit ourselves
        // to 5 pages
        int currentPageNumber = 0;
        while (feed != null && feed.getItems() != null && currentPageNumber < 5) {
          currentPageNumber++;

          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ page "+currentPageNumber+" of activities ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
          System.out.println();

          for (Activity activity : feed.getItems()) {

            show(activity);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println();
          }

          // Fetch the next page
    //      System.out.println("next token: " + feed.getNextPageToken());
    //      listActivities.setPageToken(feed.getNextPageToken());
    //      feed = listActivities.execute();
        }
      }

      /**
       * Get the most recent activity for the authenticated user.
       *
       * @throws IOException if unable to call API
       */
      private static void getActivity() throws IOException {
        // A known public activity ID
        String activityId = "z12gtjhq3qn2xxl2o224exwiqruvtda0i";

        // We do not need to be authenticated to fetch this activity
        header("Get an explicit public activity by ID");
        try {
          Activity activity = unauthenticatedPlus.activities().get(activityId).execute();
          show(activity);
        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
          log.severe(Util.extractError(e));
          throw e;
        }
      }

      /**
       * Get the profile for the authenticated user.
       *
       * @throws IOException if unable to call API
       */
      private static void getProfile() throws IOException {
        header("Geting your Google+ profile information here");
        try {
          Person profile = plus.people().get("me").execute();
          show(profile);
        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
          log.severe(Util.extractError(e));
          throw e;
        }
      }

      /**
       * Print the specified person on the command line.
       *
       * @param person the person to show
       */
      private static void show(Person person) {
        System.out.println("id: " + person.getId());
        System.out.println("name: " + person.getDisplayName());
        System.out.println("image url: " + person.getImage().getUrl());
        System.out.println("profile url: " + person.getUrl());
        System.out.println("AboutMe: " + person.getAboutMe());
        System.out.println("RelationshipStatus: " + person.getRelationshipStatus());
        System.out.println("Tagline: " + person.getTagline());
        System.out.println("PlacesLived: " + person.getPlacesLived());
        System.out.println("Birthday: " + person.getBirthday());
      }

      /**
       * Print the specified activity on the command line.
       *
       * @param activity the activity to show
     * @throws IOException
       */
      private static void show(Activity activity) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Id of post: " + activity.getId());
        System.out.println("Url of post: " + activity.getUrl());
        System.out.println("Content of post is: " + activity.getPlusObject().getContent());
        System.out.println("Attachments: " + activity.getPlusObject().getAttachments());
        System.out.println("No of replies: " + activity.getPlusObject().getReplies().getTotalItems());
        System.out.println("Title of post: " + activity.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Kind of post: " + activity.getKind());
        System.out.println("Actor of post: " + activity.getActor());
        System.out.println("Published time of post: " + activity.getPublished());
        System.out.println("Updated time: " + activity.getUpdated());


        Plus.Comments.List listComments = plus.comments().list(activity.getId());
        CommentFeed commentFeed = listComments.execute();
        List<Comment> comments = commentFeed.getItems();
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (Comment comment : comments)
        {
            System.out.println("Comment Id is: " +comment.getId());
            System.out.println("Content of Comment is: " +comment.getPlusObject().getContent());
            System.out.println("Comment written by: " +comment.getActor());
            System.out.println("Published time of Comment is: " +comment.getPublished());
            System.out.println("\n");
        }



      }


      private static void header(String name) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("============== " + name + " ==============");
        System.out.println();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please next time only include the *relevant* parts of your code. See how I edited your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12363634/1467115).

Answer (score 0):

The official [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) currently has no support for getting the persons in a circle or their posts, so this is not possible for now.

There's an open feature request regarding such kind of accesses in Google's project tracker [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=9&q=circles&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary).